# Using QGIS, how can I create attributes within a polygon layer based from a selection in that layer?

Tags: shapefile, layers, fields-attributes, select-by-location, create

I'd like to add a column, or attribute rather, to selected rows within a polygon layer. I would simply like to make a binary system, where those that are selected receive a "1,' let's say, and all others are represented by a "0." How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind- using edit > field calculator > and entering a value for only selected features should do the trick! I can replace NULL values using field calculator from there.

Comment: Is this a question? Or did you answer your own question?

Comment: It was a question, and then yes, I answered it myself. Whoops- should have done some more investigation before posting. Apologies!

Comment: No problem. I wasn't sure if you needed any more help ;-)